# Arc-connected, but not local arc-connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Question: Is there a topological space $X$ is arc-connected, but isn't local arc-connected?

Please give me some examples.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thank you, I gotta read this text now.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE.

Perhaps the most classical example is the following "comb".

Let $$X=(\mathbb R \times \{0\})\bigcup (\mathbb Q\times[0,1]),$$

where the topology of $X$ is inherit from the standard topology of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, In a subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^{2}$, are the arc-connected  be equivalent to the path-connected. I notice that, in some case, arc-connected is **stronger** than path-connected.